# New design makes the deleted comments tooltip near-invisible

Tags: bug, design, moderators

And I bet Stéphane thought we were done!

Looks like the blue background of the map on the main site is almost exactly the same as the deleted comments tooltip that mods see after a comment thread has been cleaned up.

[image: Deleted comments tooltip]
[Convenient Example Question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/30237/)

In the grand scheme of things not a big issue and something most folks will never have to see, but if the box color (or text color) can be changed to something that contrasts with the background it would be helpful.

Comment: With the total global population of 3 people seeing this issue outside the StackOverflow office, do you think they will care about this? Although it is a small CSS fix.

Comment: @Farhan Moderators can be a whiny bunch :-)